# Реализация механизма выдачи уведомлений в Web-приложении

Tags: javascript, angular2, frontend, backend

Вопрос - есть веб-приложение на angular 2, каким образом можно реализовать постоянное получение уведомления о каких-либо действиях с сервера (backend на Google Cloud Platform - App engine). Мне приходил вариант постоянно опрашивать в вечном цикле сервер, однако это не выход, или по крайней мере реализация будет затратной. Какие есть варианты механизмы live-уведомлений, а именно их отдачи с сервера на фронт?

Comment: вот здесь про angular & websockets хорошо написано https://medium.com/@lwojciechowski/websockets-with-angular2-and-rxjs-8b6c5be02fac

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то возможно WebSocket и event-driven архитектура поможет Вам решить Вашу проблему. Изменения на сервере будут отправлять action на фронт, где уже слушатели будут реагировать на это должным образом.